# Converting raw scan data to PointCloud2 data (SICK S300)

Tags: octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I really could use some help to start with my first mapping project. So far I have a SICK S300 from which I get data like this:

> header:
>
> seq: 3814
>
> stamp:
>
> secs: 1370262735
>
> nsecs: 263812610
>
> frame_id: /base_laser_link
>
> angle_min: -1.3526301384
>
> angle_max: 1.3526301384
>
> angle_increment: 0.00872664619237
>
> time_increment: 0.000184842880117
>
> scan_time: 0.0
>
> range_min: 0.0
>
> range_max: 100.0
>
> ranges: [0.6100000143051147,
> 0.6100000143051147, [...] 1.7999999523162842, 1.7899999618530273, 1.7999999523162842, 1.7999999523162842]
>
> intensities: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, [...]
> 0.0, 0.0]

And I want to work with Octomap so I get a 2D map from projected map. I need only a 2D map actually, and SLAM is not relevant either as there will be seperate odometry devices. I only want to use things with either the BSD or the LGPL licence.

By now I understand the data format I have there, here's what I still don't get:

> 1. Is there a converter which can convert this data directly to pointcloud2 data?
> 2. If so, I can add seperate odometry data to that, right?
> 3. Where do I have to put the data (remapping of topics?) to get octomap or any other map system to work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64209/converting-raw-scan-data-to-pointcloud2-data-(sick-s300)/) by [Bernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4949/bernhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to do 3D mapping with Octomap you should get a 3D sensor or a tilting unit for your 2D laser scanner. Also you have to perform some localization for inserting the scans into the octomap.

Octomap is not designed as a solution to the SLAM-problem. If you want to do 2D SLAM with your laserscanner i would recommend [gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping) or [hector mapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping) as a starting point.

Btw: Your min- and max-angle seem somewhat small for a scanner that should have 270° FoV. (And the max-range seems a little high, but i dont know the specifics of this particular model)

---

Edit:

1.) Have a look at the [laser_filter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_filters) (and [laser_geometry](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_geometry)) packages. They provide functionality to convert laser scans to point clouds. (Look at [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/11232/how-to-turn-laser-scan-to-point-cloud-map/))

2.) Odometry data is added to the scans/clouds through transforms. You define a frame for your scans/clouds and have to provide a valid transform from your fixed frame to the sensor frame. (Recommended reading: [tf tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#Tutorials))

3.) You have to publish your clouds either directly under the input topic of octomap or you have to start the octomap_server with topic remappings (renaming) through command line or launch files.

P.S.: Mapping only through odometry and dead reckoning is not very robust. You should consider more advanced methods for localization. :)

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4949/bernhard/) on 2013-06-03**:
Updated my question a little, but I'll summarize what I missed out on explaining: I'm only interested in 2D mapping right now, SLAM is not important as the vehicles will have seperate odometry, and I only want to use programs with either LGPL or BSD as a licence. Thanks for pointing the angles out.

**Comment by [Bernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4949/bernhard/) on 2013-06-04**:
So that's the things I've been searching for! 1: I'll need to work through this, but now I know where to start so that'll be easy. 2/3: I thought so, now I know for sure.

PS: The answer works but care to elaborate on the better methods for localization? I'd think specific odometry sensors would do?

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-06-04**:
Most of the time you want to localize relative to a given map (or the map you are currently building -> SLAM). So you would usually localize with the same sensors you are using for mapping. (Like laser scanner with AMCL in a prebuilt map)

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-06-04**:
For absolute localization within an external coordinate system, you will need external beacons (like GPS outdoors or some indoor positioning systems).

**Comment by [Bernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4949/bernhard/) on 2013-06-04**:
I was thinking of using said beacons for total positioning, and I'm not sure how applicable SLAM is in my case, it will be a production environment. I will need to consider both options, but for now I should get the next step down so I can see which path to pursue.